# Chef support of MS Windows

Tags: chef-infra

I'm investigating the viability of using Chef to manage MS Windows nodes. On my Ubuntu desktop I installed the Chef Infra Client: 15.0.300. This is fairly up-to-date chef-client per my understanding.

```
[user:~/chef] master+ 10 ± knife --version
Chef Infra Client: 15.0.300
```

I noticed that the `winrm` sub-command is not part of default Chef Infra Client. There is also little to no documentation on how to add this sub-command to my client.

Is managing MS Windows nodes still a supported or viable option when using Chef 15? It seems Chef dropped support for it.

The strange thing is that I was able to bootstrap my node. So there seems to be still something left in Infra client that supports MS Windows. So for example the command below does work

```
knife bootstrap -o winrm 1.1.1.100 -U user -P '******' --node-name mywinnode
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chef Workstation software (https://downloads.chef.io/products/workstation) contains the knife command line tool and other Chef Infra management tools where the Chef Infra Client (https://downloads.chef.io/products/infra-client) only has the client software for managing system configurations on Chef nodes.

Chef Infra Client 15 is still supported on Windows. See supported platforms here: https://docs.chef.io/platforms/